# Alfresco JavaScript/Rhino multi-thread processing and concurrency

Tags: javascript, alfresco, rhino

Let's consider two separate Alfresco Rhino-JavaScript tasks that compete for create the same folder:

```
var shared = companyhome.childByNamePath("shared");
var newFolderName = "folder-x";
var newFolder = shared.childByNamePath(newFolderName);
if (newFolder==null) {
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(10000);//remove this line in second thread
    newFolder = shared.createFolder(newFolderName);
    if (newFolder==null){
        logger.error("error: "+newFolderName);
    } else {
        logger.info("success: "+newFolderName);
    }
} else {
    logger.info("already exists: "+newFolderName);
}
```

If we run the first script with sleep (10 sec) and the second script without sleep then:

- the second script will create the folder "folder-x"
- the first script will rise "File or folder folder-x already exists" exception

Let's imagine a lot of competing threads trying to create random folders.
Is there something like semaphores or atomic-operation that blocks only creating specified folder (non-blocking for other folders)?

Comment: you just need to check after the sleep instead of before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I get it, it was trivial...

The method `createFolder()` is atomic and we just need to handle exception if folder was already created:

```
var getOrCreateFolder = function(parent, newFolderName){
    var newFolder = parent.childByNamePath(newFolderName);
    if (newFolder==null) {
        try {
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(10000);//remove this line in second thread
            newFolder = parent.createFolder(newFolderName);
            return {folder:newFolder,isNew:true};

        } catch (e) {
            newFolder = parent.childByNamePath(newFolderName);
            if (newFolder!=null){
                return {folder:newFolder,isNew:false};
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return {folder:newFolder,isNew:false};
    }
};

var shared = companyhome.childByNamePath("shared");
var newFolderName = "folder-x";
var folderDto = getOrCreateFolder(shared,newFolderName);
if (folderDto.folder==null) {
    logger.error("error: "+newFolderName);
} else {
    logger.info("done: "+newFolderName+", new: "+folderDto.isNew);
}
```